# Unable to open my database on sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created a database with Visual Studio 2010. I see the .mdf file. I have populated it with tables and data. However, I am unable to open it using SQL Server Management studio. Why is that?

Comment: Where is this MDF located?

Comment: Are you trying to attach it?

Comment: I moved the DB elsewhere. It's working now. Thanks! :D